# How can I export a .ui file for a pygi window that I build dynamically?

Tags: application-development, pygi

I understand that building things with the MVC mindset is a good thing.  I also understand that if you separate code maintenance and UI, that Glade UI files make it easier for non-programming people to offer UI improvements.  The question is this:

I'm better at generating the widgets I need dynamically from code.  How can I generate UI files from some dynamically generated window?

Ex: assuming main_win is an instance of the window for which I want a UI file, is there a way to do `Gtk.Builder.generate_ui(main_win)` or something similar? I looked at the Builder documentation and I know that no similar functions exist there, but how can I do something like this?

Comment: You could generate the xml file completely or write your own helper class. The GtkBuilder format is fully documented and you can use one of the many xml libraries for Python. I however wouldn't put any work into this, just use your manually written PyGI code in your application.